# How do I use an MVC Role permission in a View?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

How can I apply permission in a View based on a Set of users in a Role.

For example, how can I show a Create Article button for a role Editor and hide it for a role Reader?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its best practice to get the Controller to set a property on the ViewModel, then the View can check for this and it also makes the logic more easily testable.

Its the Models job is to be the communicator with the View.
Then security logic doesn't leak into the View.

In your controller you could do something like:

```
model.IsEditor = User.IsInRole("editor")
model.IsReader = User.IsInRole("reader")
```

Then if you view you could do the following:

```
@if (model.IsEditor)
{
  // show editor button
}

@if (model.IsReader)
{
  // show reader button
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! Great idea! Can you share a simple sample?

Comment: Great! Do you use WebSecurity from WebMatrix for authentication?

Comment: No, that doesn't support roles out of the box. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity%28v=vs.111%29.aspx

Comment: Use the standard Asp.Net membership, it has roles built in.

Answer (score 4):

There are two schools of thought on this.

One school says that you create separate views for roles.  So you create a RoleEditor view and a RoleReader view.  And, in relatively simple applications this is probably the best approach.

If your views are more complex, and require "on the fly" rendering based on role, then you follow an approach more like Ralph suggests.  You do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    // IsUserAnEditor is a placeholder for a method to determine whether the user
    // is an editor based on whatever role technology you're using.
    MyModel model = new MyModel { IsEditor = IsUserAnEditor() }
    return View(model);
}
```

Then in your view, you have code like this:

```
@model MyModel

....

@if(Model.IsEditor)
{
    // Code to add the "Edit" link, this is just an example, customize for your needs
    <span>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "MyController", new { id=Model.ID })
    </span>
}
```

Comment: The logic should almost always populate a ViewModel before making it to the view.  Makes the ViewModel more reusable, and removes logic from views which is typically frowned upon.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - I don't understand your point, that's exactly what i'm doing.

Comment: I'm agreeing with your post, up-voting it and describing it in a more abstract way.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - Gotcha, sorry... sounded like you were correcting me ;)