# How do I get model information into the _layout.vbhtml?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, authorize-attribute

VS2013, MVC5 VB

In this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094635/how-do-i-use-an-mvc-role-permission-in-a-view) the case is clearly stated that we should keep logic out of the view, and it demonstrates how to put simple Booleans into the view model.

But if the menu item I want to hide based on a role is in the _layout.vbhtml partial view, how do I get model information to that partial view code?  I understand how I could pass the model information to a partial view called from a view, but the _layout is automatically called for every view.  The models would be expected to be different for different views.

I currently have:

```
@If User.IsInRole("Admin") Then
```

in the partial view code for _layout because I couldn't immediately see how I put that logic into a method for _layout.

Answer (score 0):

The model you pass in from your action will be available in your _layout view. Some things you can do:

- Derive your view model from a base view model and have a strongly typed model in your _layout view

  `@model BaseViewModel`
- Use a dynamic type model (EDIT: just noticed you're using VB, don't think this may be an option for you)

  `@model dynamic`

More info on [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/views/dynamic-v-strongly-typed-views)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that whatever partial you're trying to render doesn't require anything that can't be acquired in a single action, you can do something like this:

#### _Layout.vbhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    @Html.Action("someaction", "widget")

    @RenderBody()
</html>
```

#### Your action

```
Public Class WidgetController Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    Public Function SomeAction() As ActionResult

        Dim model As New YourViewModel()

        Return PartialView("_partialViewName", model)
    End Function

End Class
```

`Html.Action()` will return the result of whatever action method you call; assuming that result is HTML, it gets injected into the rendered layout, similar to an `include` in PHP (assuming you've ever used PHP). Returning a partial view means that _Layout won't be "called" when rendering the view.